# Deadlock on logging variable value changes using a SQL task

Tags: ssis, deadlock

Morning

I've been reading "SQL Server 2008 Integration Services Problem - Design - Solution". It outlines a way of logging variable changes which I'm trying to replicate in SQL 2005.

1. Create variables e.g. PackageId, RecordsAffected. - Set Raise ChangeEvent to true.
2. Create a string variable g.g. strVariableValue. - Set Raise ChangeEvent to false.
3. On the package event handler: OnVariableValueChanged add a script task "SCR Convert value to string".
4. Add ReadOnlyVariables: System::VariableValue
5. Add ReadWriteVariables: User::strVariableValue
6. In the script, set a local variable to System::VariableValue.value.tostring
7. Set the variable User::strVariableValue to the local variable
8. Add an "Execute SQL Task" component "SQL Log Variable Value Changed" calling a SP with no resultsets.
9. Set parameter mapping to User::PackageId, System::VariableName, User::strVariableValue

When this is run, I get a deadlock on User::PackageID

Error: 0xC001405B at SQL Log Variable Value Changed: A deadlock was detected while trying to lock variable "User::_PackageID" for read access. A lock could not be acquired after 16 attempts and timed out.

The script step succeeds but the Execute SQL task fails. I'm using Visual Studio 2005 Version 8.0.50727.42, Microsoft SQL Server Integration Services Designer Version 9.00.4035.00 and BIDSHelper Version 1.4.3.0.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eureka!

I had the same problem and led to a few deadend posts, then I discovered the root.

I had the framework working just fine and wanted to force some info to be logged.
So I changed the value of the framework variable "strVariableValue" and this caused the deadlock with the change event task.
I fixed by creating my own variable "strLogMe" and putting whatever I wanted to log.

Moral: don't touch the framework variables

Answer (score 0):

Did you use the code sample from the book?  All the files are available on the [Wiley website for free](http://media.wiley.com/product_ancillary/62/04705257/DOWNLOAD/CH02%20Framework%20Code.zip).  The code sample includes a SSIS package, sql scripts, and VB code for the script.  If this doesn't work for you, then let me know since one of my team members found a way to log variable changes that was different from this methodology.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error ("a deadlock was detected" etc), suddenly, which seemed to coincide with I.T. having done a Microsoft Windows patch on the server.  There were packages which were using script tasks, with read-only and/or read-write variables in the SSIS UI.  Even though it seemed to have been an environmental issue (because the packages had worked for months, then suddenly stopped working, even though I hadn't changed any code), I thought, well (as I had seen from various blog posts from years gone by), there were instances of companies doing server patches, then having their SSIS packages break; and the blogs seemed to say, change the way you're locking the variables, don't reference them in the UI; instead, lock them explicitly in code.  So I tried the same thing.  It didn't fix it.

It turns out some individual had removed the permissions of the user under whose identity the packages run, from the AD group; those permissions were required because it was trying to copy a file from a directory which required read permissions on the directory.  These packages are typically called by a SQL agent job using a proxy identity.  When the package was executed manually from SSMS, it worked.  But when it was run by calling the SQL agent job, it failed.

The bottom line is, it was just coincidence that the packages started failing around the time of the Windows update.  But the other (main) point is, if your package is trying to access a file on the network, and the identity (or proxy identity) under which that package runs does not have permissions to the source or target directory, then your package could fail and the problem could manifest itself in this cryptic way, where it looks like a variable deadlock issue, but it's actually a file share permissions issue.  I only wasted a day on this, but... maybe this will be useful to somebody in the future.